# How to filter one data frame based on another dataframe cell values present as a condition?

Tags: r

I have First data frame as

```
feature  feature_weight    feature_desc
A        0.046891755        -0.831 < A      
B        -0.036292305       B <= -0.243     
C        0.008370983        0.317 < C       
D        0.007841638        0.212 < D
```

Second Data Frame as

```
variable   binning     percent
A          ar1         -0.224
A          ar2         0.715
A          ar3         -0.831
B          br1         -0.243
B          br2         -0.016
B          br3         0.128
C          cr1         0.102
C          cr2         0.317
C          cr3         -0.022
D          dr1         -0.522
D          dr2         0.212
D          dr3         -0.589
```

I need the binning values in the Second data frame to be added as new column in First data frame, but only those specific values filtered out from the character data type of feature_desc column, as below

```
feature  feature_weight    feature_desc   binning
A        0.046891755        -0.831 < A    ar3       
B        -0.036292305       B <= -0.243   br1   
C        0.008370983        0.317 < C     cr2   
D        0.007841638        0.212 < D     dr2
```

The feature_desc is a character type

Comment: gsub("[^0-9\\.\\-]", "", df1$feature_desc) : I could filter out the numerics from the column using gsub

Comment: I think your question is unclear because it is removing the comparison and then do a merge with equality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you filter out the numerics, we can `merge` the two dataframes to get `binning` value.

```
df1$value <- gsub("[^0-9\\.\\-]", "", df1$feature_desc) 

merge(df1, df2, by.x = c("feature", "value"), by.y = c("variable", "percent"))


#  feature  value feature_weight feature_desc binning
#1       A -0.831    0.046891755   -0.831 < A     ar3
#2       B -0.243   -0.036292305  B <= -0.243     br1
#3       C  0.317    0.008370983    0.317 < C     cr2
#4       D  0.212    0.007841638    0.212 < D     dr2
```

You can delete the `value` column later if not needed.

Answer (score 1):

I filtered the numerics as new_values

```
gsub("[^0-9\\.\\-]", "", df1$feature_desc)
```

Then removed the duplicates of variable in df2 based on value from df1

```
df3 %>%  filter(percent %in% df1$new_values)
```

then merged both

```
merge(df3, df4, by.x='variable', by.y='feature')
```